# Camel custom component: perform two different actions

Tags: components, apache-camel

I just want to know if I can do below pertaining to custom component

1)  I created a sample component

```
somComponent://foo ---> what this foo refers to?can i have any string there?
 What does it denotes?
```

2) consider below route

```
   from("some blah")
   .to(someCustomComponent://action1)
   .to(someCustomComponent://action2);
```

Idea - I want to perform two different actions on the above. Kind of two different methods.

Is the above possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation for your custom component in Apache Camel can be described as follows:

```
someComponent://instance?parm1=foo&parm2=bar
```

The `instance` part can be pretty much anything you want to uniquely identify the endpoint.

You can derive `DefaultComponent` and implement the methods. The signature for `createEndpoint` method looks like this:

```
protected Endpoint createEndpoint(final String uri, String remaining,
        Map<String, Object> parameters) throws Exception
```

So for the endpoint *someComponent://instance?parm1=foo&parm2=bar*

```
uri = someComponent://instance?parm1=foo&parm2=bar
remaining = instance
parmeters = (Map) parm1 -> foo, parm2 -> bar
```

Therefore, yes! You can easily denote the `action` you want, for example as a parameter such as:

```
someComponent://instance?action=something
```

Comment: Thanks much for the reply.I somehow figured that out.But wanted to check if that is the right of way of doing it...